# Clean Trim Filtered Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I use this function to clean and trim selected data.

When I filter the range and apply this function on filtered cell it copies and paste the above value till down.

Before applying the function:

[image]

After applying the function:

[image]

```vb
Sub CleanTrim()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Value))
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through the `Areas` in `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and apply the trimming to each area in turn - it will not work on a discontinuous range like the one you typically get from `SpecialCells`

```vb
Sub CleanTrim()
    Dim a As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each a In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        a.NumberFormat = "@"
        a.Value = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(a.Value))
    Next a
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```